# JNI method returns old data

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've spent whole day on this problem and still have no idea how to solve it.

Here is the simplified code

JAVA

```
class javaclass{
private volatile boolean isTerminated;
  public void javamethod()
  {
  log.logInfo("java :"+isTerminated());
  }

  public int isTerminated()
  {
    return (isTerminated) ? 1 : 0;
  }

  public doJob()
  {
    executeNative();
  }

  private native int executeNative() throws Exception;
}
```

C++

```
bool cmethod()
{
cerr << "JNI " << wrapper::isTerminated() << "\n";
if(wrapper::isTerminated)
  return false;
jni->CallVoidMethod(self, apiJavamethod, xPoint); 
return true;
//apiJavamethod is jMethodId of javamethod
}

int wrapper::isTerminated()
{
  return jni->CallIntMethod(self, apiIsTerminated);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL NAMESPACE_javaclass_executeNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject self) {
  for(int i=0;i < _ITERATIONS;++i)
  {
    if(!cmethod())
      break;
  }

}
```

C++ cmethod is executed in some loop, which stops when C++ catches isTerminated().
In output i see:

....
....

in log:
java 0
java 1
java 1
java 1

in console:
JNI 0
JNI 0
JNI 0
JNI 1

So, JNI is somehow behind the real state of variable.
It produces an important bug in application (((

Maybe it's some problem with java itself? (v.1.5, i forced to used it)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are printing to stdout from Java, and to stderr from C++. You cannot be certain about the way these are interleaved by your terminal. To be sure about what's happening, print to the same stream from both languages, and flush the stream after printing.

Comment: oh, i see, thx. it's simplified example, in actual code in java i use some GUI logger (the program itself is a plugin to CAD)

Comment: I suggest your give more code, there isn't even a native method in your code so far.

Comment: If the output is really like this (`java` is printed first), then it's the problem Thomas mentioned I think. From the source code it should start with `JNI 0`, then `java 0`. Have you tried printing only from Java in the meantime?

Comment: They do print independently (C++ to console, java to log in CAD's GUI). It's not the order of prints that means here - see some edits in code.
Sorry that i confused you.

Comment: So that is the last prints that mean something.
Java prints "1" last 3 times, while Cpp just one and stops executing

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to diagnose what's wrong, the code that you pasted seems to be OK. However, what is `xPoint`? How is the `isTerminated` variable modified? How are the `api...` variables created?

Comment: Thx, you seem to be the only person interested...
`isTerminated` modified in some *try-catch* in java
api... variables are set by jni calls as this
  `jni->GetMethodID(apiClassId, "isTerminated", "()I")`
jni initializes them correctly, assert() checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing all the synchronization in one language or the other.  It's looking like "volatile" isn't being respected across the boundary for some reason.  Something like:

```
public doJob()
{
  while(!isTerminated)
    executeNative();
}
```

Comment: So did i. Code a bit more complicated, but idea the same. It works, of course...

The thing is - i still don't understand how this problem appeared and where i can find some standard docs where JNI behavior is described in detail...

Comment: This is likely a bug with the implementation rather than specified behavior.  It may work fine on another operating system, for example.  You'd probably have to look at the source code to see how it works.